# Gesture recognizor on UICollectionView not receiving gestures

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have a ViewController with a vertically scrolling collection view that takes up the entire view. I want to be able to get swipe and pan gestures on the entire collection view (not just on cells) but I can't get any gestures. I have tried adding the gesture recognizer to the view and the collection view but neither seem to work.

Adding the gesture recognizer to the view

```
self.panEdgeGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
self.panEdgeGesture.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:self.panEdgeGesture];
[self.panEdgeGesture setEdges:UIRectEdgeRight];
```

Then I added these functions:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
   shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

   return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}

- (void)handlePan:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
 DebugLog(@"Received pan gesture");
}
```

Could the collection view cells stop the gesture events from triggering? They have no gestures themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Per [UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer's Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer_class/index.html):

> After creating a screen edge pan gesture recognizer, assign an
>   appropriate value to the edges property before attaching the gesture
>   recognizer to your view. You use this property to specify from which
>   edges the gesture may start. This gesture recognizer ignores any
>   touches beyond the first touch.

So change you code to:

```
self.panEdgeGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc];
[self.panEdgeGesture setEdges:UIRectEdgeRight];
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
self.panEdgeGesture.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:self.panEdgeGesture];
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is an important note, but is not the issue causing the gestures to fail. I tried the same code on am empty view controller without a collection view and it works, so I am trying to understand how to add it to a view controller that has a collection view.

Comment: You'll have to post more code because I can copy your code and get it to work with a collectionView provided I make the change I mentioned. Where are you setting up the gestureRecognizer? Set a breakpoint to confirm it is getting called. It's weird that you are typing sender as UISwipeGestureRecognizer when you are having UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer call it.

Comment: You're right it should have been changed - previously I had a swipe gesture. In fact, I finally tracked down the error to another function that reset the collection view. So you are right, the code does work.